# simple renaming of file in cpp without the need to write anything in it

Tags: c++, c

My `pcl` module produces an output file `result.pcd`. This said module runs in a loop, so it takes up to 100 `pcd` files and for each iteration produces an output file `result.pcd`. The thing is this `result.pcd` gets overwritten in every iteration, so before the next iteration I'm trying to rename this file. I want this file to be named incrementally (i.e `file1.pcd`, `file2.pcd`, `file3.pcd`...)

My renaming code doesn't fit the syntax. Please help me with this.

My aim is not to write anything in the new file, rather to rename an old one incrementally. (Please include comments and headers in code.)

If my method of thinking is wrong, I need expert advice on pointing me to the right direction.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    while (true) 
    {
        int k = 1;
        char newname[] = "file%i.txt", k;
        rename("result.pcd", newname);
        k++;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The new file gets renamed as `file%i.txt` rather than `file1.txt`

Comment: seems like you forgot to call `sprintf` or the like.

Comment: You might want to look into sprintf( ... ) or use std::string

Comment: Look into using a `stringstream` -- http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/ I think you're using too much C library stuff when there's perfectly good C++ solutions

Comment: @Peri461 or the question is mistagged ;)

Comment: @Borgleader the title of the question itself addresses a "file in `cpp`"

Comment: @Peri461 I know but I've seen a few users say "theyre doing c++" when in fact theyre learning/programming in C, hence the question should be retagged as C.

Comment: Surely the rename will fail in the second time around the loop

Comment: `return(0)` - `return` is a statement, not a function. The parentheses are unnecessary and obfuscatory. Besides, your `while` loop seems pointless: it would loop forever, which would be bad, but then you defeat it by unconditionally `return`ing at the end of the 1st iteration, which means there's no point having a loop.

Comment: I'm surprised this code even compiles. There is an illegal variable redeclaration.

Comment: Please try to take a bit longer to make your writing legible.

Comment: All i needed was a hint and i got it.Thank you @Borgleader and RatHat was your valuable suggestions.

Comment: the while loop forms a part of my code, the header and this part of code was used for testing purpose only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your valuable suggestions.sprintf() was the solution to my problem.Hears the code for future help for somebody.

```
    int k = 1;
    char filename[16]; 
    sprintf( filename, "file%d.txt", k );  
    rename("file.txt", filename);
    k++;
    return(0);
```

Comment: What is the point of `k++;`? What is the point of `k`. Why not just write `rename("file.txt", "file1.txt")`

Comment: just as I mentioned in my question i have over 500 files and i cant rename everything manually. Wanted them to be renamed incrementally.